# How to simulate encrypted communication between storage and computing cloud

Tags: java, cloud, aes

I know from my fellow classmates that this isn't site for homeworks, but any help or pointers from you esteemed guys would be great.

Using [CloudAnalyst](http://www.cloudbus.org/cloudsim/) I need to simulate the following:

ONE OPERATION MUST BE PERFORMED ON A FILE WHICH WILL SHOW THE
COMMUNICATION BETWEEN STORAGE AND COMPUTING CLOUD IN WHICH COMMUNICATION WILL BE
ENCRYPTED ALSO (Example of operation could be COUNTING THE WORDS or anything better).

The CloudAnalyst part shall look like follows:

1. In the simulation window new tab has been created named as “File
   Configuration”
2. In File to Operate we choose the file on which we want to apply the
   encryption technique.
3. In the file encryption policy user can apply AES 128 bit or Selective
   Encryption using AES Algorithm at a time.

I got the following article : http://clean-clouds.com/2012/02/08/how-to-run-and-configure-cloudanalyst/
But it didn't help much, hope anyone of you will.

Thanks in advance.